# Positioning absolute DIV to page outside of relative DIV

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, css-position

I have an absolute div inside a relative div. It's essentially a container for a absolute positioned corner banner, on the top right side of the page.

It works fine with Chrome, but not with IE. In IE it appears positioned absolutely, but inside its container. I'd like to override this, if possible, due to the way this site is built (complete template on a CMS):

```
#corner-banner a {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
display: block;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background: url(../images/down.png) no-repeat;
text-indent: -999em;
text-decoration: none;
}

#corner-banner a:hover {
background: url(../images/up.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks for reading and for any input.

Cheers!

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are saying, but it sounds like the website is behaving as it should in IE. The inner absolute positioned div is in the top right of the parent container?. That is exactly what `position: relative` does. It means that children set to absolute, will be relative to that container and not the page. AND in your description you are talking about `div`'s but your css targets `a`'s.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Regarding the a tag vs div's, I had the sand problem with div's only, but used the a tag for better ie rollover behavior.

Comment: And about the expected behavior of ie and relative tags - I understand that, but that's exactly what I am trying to circumvent. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any difference. We need a link or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct behavior.  Absolute position inside a relatively positioned element will be absolutely positioned relative to the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the parent relative container is a div and not a td ?

**EDIT**

ok

This is not a CSS problem, but a bad HTML organization.
So, if you want your element to be positioned by the window, and not by his relative parent coordonates, you must put it outside the relative element.

Something like that :

```
<body>
  <div id="corner-banner" class="norelative_element">
    <!-- Your content with absolute position by the window !-->
    <a>...</a>
  </div>
  <div class="relative_element">
    <!-- Your content with relative position !-->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yep, it's inside a div, not a table td.